# Configure same Internet Explorer zone mappings with and without ESC via GPO

Tags: active-directory, security, group-policy, internet-explorer

Our Active Directory domain consisting of Windows Server 2012 R2 servers and Windows 7 workstations configures Internet Explorer security zones using this Group Policy setting:

`Computer Configuration/Policies/Administrative Template/Windows Components/Internet Explorer/Internet Control Panel/Security Page/Site to Zone Assignment List`

However, this has no effect on the servers, which have IE Enhanced Security Configuration enabled. How do I configure them using Group Policy? Ideally, I'd want the same settings to apply both with and without ESC without listing them twice.

Comment: Did you tried the same setting from User Configuration, not Computer. I guess your server act as terminal server ?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but we have "Security Zones: Use only machine settings" enabled and I don't want to change that. Users connect to that server via RDP, yes.

Answer (score 2):

> There are separate settings under each ZoneMap key for “ESC on” and
>   “ESC off”.  If ESC is on, only those settings under the **EscDomains and
>   EscRanges subkeys are used;** if ESC is off, only the settings under the
>   Domains and Ranges subkeys are used.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

As you want a machine setting, those would be configured like that;

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\EscDomains\mytest.org ... ]

As the settings is not there via the normal ZoneMap GPO setting, I recommand a GPP to set the registry item within your GPO

Comment: I tried this, but it had no effect. That is, the registry value was added, but my Trusted Sites zone is still empty when I view it in Internet Settings. (There were already other domains listed under the `EscDomains` registry key, such as runonce.msn.com, and they don't appear under Trusted Sites, either.)

Comment: @EM I seen report that if the two branches are set, Domain & EscDomain a bug can happen, thus leading to your bug (empty list). Is it something you can test out on your TS ?

Comment: Turns out it was something quite similar to that - see my answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding EscDomains registry keys per **yagmoth555**'s answer, I had to set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_IGNORE_POLICIES_ZONEMAP_IF_ESC_ENABLED_KB918915\*` to `1` (DWORD) for the registry settings to be applied.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/918915 describes the problem. I initially ignored it, because it's for Windows Server 2003 and we're running 2012 R2. It turns out that, while the hotfix doesn't need to be applied to later Windows Server versions, it still needs to be enabled using this registry key.

Comment: I tried quite a lot of permutations of this, and I don't think you do need the `FEATURE_IGNORE_POLICIES_ZONEMAP_IF_ESC_ENABLED_KB918915` key workaround beyond Windows Server 2003. I think you've just got to be careful about which key path you use to get to the `EscDomains` key. For me, when I put  my intranet sites under the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\EscDomains` key, everything worked fine. Note that there is a `Policies` key in the path, which is presumably where group policy configuration of the site/zone assignments goes.